# How use mockito so that a call on any instance of an object returns something fixed

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, powermockito

So I have a class like this:

```
public class A
{
    public String methodB()
    {
      //do something
     }
}
```

Now suppose I have the following code:

```
A a1=new A();
A a2=new A();
String b=a1.methodB();
String c=a2.methodB();
```

I want to mock using Mockito such that whenever this methodB() is called from any instance of class A, I get the same output, say "fixedstring".

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```java
public class Test {

    @Mock
    private A a;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        // Mock A behaviour
        doReturn("your-string").when(this.a).methodB();
    }

    @Test
    // Unit tests
}
```

The important part is `doReturn("your-string").when(this.a).methodB();`.

Comment: @ArnabGhosh, did this help? Let me know if something is unclear.